# Neural Network is unable to predict high values .

Tags: neural-network, chainer

I am trying to design a feed forward neural network for predicting regression values . Max value 125 and Min value is -1000 in training set for dependent values .

But after training my neural network is predicting max value as 9 and min value as -7 .

Can anyone please suggest me how can i improve predictions .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, neural network is stable to output around the value -1 ~ 1.

You can use StandardScaler, or MinMaxScaler for preprocessing to convert the target value's scale (to usually around -1 ~ 1.).

See also:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html